# Google Data Studio piechart from column with multiple values per cell

Tags: looker-studio

I have an excel spreadsheet from a Questionnaire. One of the questions was in checkbox format. The result of this question are held in a single column, and where the user has selected more that one answer, the answers are separated by comma's.

What devices do you own?  Mobile, PC, Laptop, Tablet

So in a single cell I get 'Mobile,PC' when these two are selected.

I am using Google Data Studio to visualise the data, but stuck on how to create a graph that shows all the values individually.

At the minute I get a combination for every value. So a value of 1 for 'Mobile,PC' rather than a value for 1 'PC' and '1'Mobile.

Google Data Studio doesn't allow countif statements, so a bit lost.

I have tried to TRIM, COUNIF and REGEX but none have worked.

```
Count(REGEXP_MATCH(Device, "PC"))
```

I'm a bit lost on this, tried so many combinations. If someone can put me on the right track I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve that with a pie chart without changing your data source first as it needs one dimension (Device) and then one count metric which your data doesn't seem to support.

You could create 4 metrics like

```
SUM(
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Device, "PC") then 1
ELSE 0
END
)
```

And put them into a Stacked bar / column chart. You might need to create a dimension that has a single value to avoid having multiple bars/columns.